# I can select an image from the gallery and place in a Imageview but later I can not hold it in place

Tags: ios, image, delegates, photo, galera

I can select an image from the gallery and place in a ImageView but later I can not hold it in place when changing viewController and returns the image disappears

```
-(IBAction)LibraryPicture
{
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController  alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

  }
  NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];


                }

 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
             editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
 imageSelect.image = image;
 [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


 -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)  picker
 {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {

 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 - (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"save image & Keep");
  }
```

this image It should be maintained until the user changes it again

Comment: Why tag with galera?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's going is because you're not saving the image. In your IBAction for saving the image you're doing nothing. So, you need to save the image and then in the viewdidload (When user comes back to VC), load that image.

To save it you'll need to do this:

```
NSString *imgName= @"imgname.png";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:imgName forKey:@"imageName"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];
UIImage *imageSave = image; // The imageView that you want to save
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSave);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

And To reload the image when you come back to that VC, in your viewDidload do this:

```
NSString *imgName= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"imageName"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDir,imgName];
[BackGround setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
```

Comment: I tried this before    but I have the same error                                                                                         
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165d2030'

Comment: What iOS are you targeting? and are you using a UIImageView for the image from the library?